# Typesafe config: copy a key-value from from one config to another

Tags: java, scala, typesafe-config

Suppose I have two config files:

```
val config1: Config = ... 
val config2: Config = ...
```

and I want to copy a key-value pair corresponding to the key `someKey` from `config1` to `config2`. The key-value looks like the following:

```
someKey: ["someVal", "someVal2"]
```

This is what I did first:

```
val config3 = config2.withValue("someKey", 
ConfigValueFactory.fromIterable(config1.getStringList("someKet")))
```

which is very ugly. I also tried but it gives error `has type LIST rather than OBJECT`:

```
val config3 = config2.withFallback(config1.getConfig("someKey"))
```

Any ideas for how to do this in a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
val c1: Config = ConfigFactory.parseString("x.a = 3 \n x.b = 'bbb' \n x.c = [1, 2, 3]")
val c2: Config = ConfigFactory.parseString("x.a = 4")

println(c1)
println("-----------")
println(c2)

println(c1.getInt("x.a"))
println(c2.withValue("x.c", c1.getList("x.c")))
```